# Econml summary() interpretation

Tags: python, causality, treatment-effect, heterogeneity

I just started using EconML library, I would like to ask what does the output of inference summary mean? what exactly is the prediction/inference doing here?

UPDATE: Also, I don't understand about the p-value, isn't it a prediction here? Why use the metric from the hypothesis test?

```
   point_estimate  stderr  zstat  pvalue  ci_lower  ci_upper
X                                                           
0          -0.602   0.106 -5.672   0.000    -0.776    -0.427
1          -0.042   0.085 -0.487   0.627    -0.182     0.099
2          -0.161   0.125 -1.295   0.195    -0.366     0.044
```

Why would there be a statistic like stderr for each row (`each sample`)? My understanding an single sample does not have a `stderr`, so with whom is it compared and calculated?

My test code, mostly copied from official examples:

````py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


# DoubleML 
from scipy.linalg import toeplitz

from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.datasets import make_spd_matrix

from doubleml import DoubleMLData


# EconML 
from econml.dml import LinearDML
from sklearn.linear_model import (Lasso, LassoCV, LogisticRegression,
                                  LogisticRegressionCV,LinearRegression,
                                  MultiTaskElasticNet,MultiTaskElasticNetCV)
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor,RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from econml.inference import BootstrapInference
from itertools import product
# DATA: Simulate data

# Treatment effect function
def exp_te(x):
    return np.exp(2*x[0])

# DGP constants
np.random.seed(123)
n = 2000
n_w = 30
support_size = 5
n_x = 10
# Outcome support
support_Y = np.random.choice(np.arange(n_w), size=support_size, replace=False)
coefs_Y = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=support_size)
epsilon_sample = lambda n: np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=n)
# Treatment support
support_T = support_Y
coefs_T = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=support_size)
eta_sample = lambda n: np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=n)

# Generate controls, covariates, treatments and outcomes
W = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(n, n_w))
X = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=(n, n_x))
# X = W

# Heterogeneous treatment effects
# TE = np.array([exp_te(x_i) for x_i in X])
TE = 0.2 + 0.3 * X[:,0] - 0.2 * X[:,2] + X[:,3] - 2 * X[:,5] + 0.2 * X[:,9]
T = np.dot(W[:, support_T], coefs_T) + eta_sample(n)
Y = TE * T + np.dot(W[:, support_Y], coefs_Y) + epsilon_sample(n)

Y_train, Y_val, T_train, T_val, X_train, X_val, W_train, W_val = train_test_split(Y, T, X, W, test_size=.2)
# Generate test data
# X_test = np.array(list(product(np.arange(0, 1, 0.01), repeat=n_x)))
X_test = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=(3, n_x))
# Estimation Methods: simulation
# est = LinearDML(model_y=LassoCV(),model_t=LassoCV())
est = LinearDML(model_y=RandomForestRegressor(),
                model_t=RandomForestRegressor(),
                random_state=123)

### Estimate with OLS confidence intervals

#simulation
est.fit(Y_train, T_train, X=X_train, W=W_train)
te_pred = est.effect(X_test)
lb, ub = est.effect_interval(X_test, alpha=0.05) # OLS confidence intervals

pnt_coef = est.coef_
lb_coef,ub_coef = est.coef__interval(alpha=.05)

# print(f"{te_pred},\n,{lb},\n,{ub}")
# print()
# print()
# # print(f"{pnt_coef},\n,{lb_coef},\n,{ub_coef}")

print(pnt_coef)

print(est.summary())

# x_0 0.3 , x_2 -0.2, x_3 1,  x_5 -2, x_9 0.2
print(est.effect_inference(X_test).summary_frame(alpha=0.1,value=0,decimals=3))
```
````